# How can I set a node as selected in winforms treeview without searching for it

Tags: winforms, treeview

When I say:

```
treeview.SelectedNode = new TreeNode{ Text = "Myname" };
```

This will not work although there is a node in the treeview nodes collection with this text.

How can I set a node as selected programatically without searching for the node instance before and then select it?

Answer (score 2):

When you are adding a node you can set a key for it as well, for example:

```
treeview.Nodes.Add("a node", "a node");
treeview.Nodes.Add("b node", "b node");
```

That way if you want to select a node you can do it by using its key, for example:

```
treeview.SelectedNode = treeView.Nodes.Find("b node", true);
```

This way you can avoid the need to iterate all the nodes manually checking if their text matches.

Comment: This did not work in my case sorry. The node returned by .Nodes[MyName/Key] is always null although the node is inside the nodes collection with the key/name.

Comment: Does the above example but with treeview.SelectedNode = treeView.Nodes.Find("node key", true); works for you ?

Comment: The code above works as well, I'm assuming you have Parent nodes and you are looking for the node in them, hence why it didn't work, I will update my answer using the Find method. In case you don't want to use the Find method the principle is still the same as the code I posted before (assuming you have subnodes). treeview.Nodes["master node key"].Nodes["sub node key"];

Comment: I already used the Find method and I have to stick to that approach due to my recursive hierarchy.

Comment: How do you set the Key on a previously created Node or for that matter set the key on a Node when creating it? It seems that you can't and one is forced to create the Node while adding to the Nodes collection if you want the key to be specified. I can see assigning the key when adding to a collection but why is there not a .Add (Node, key) overload?

Comment: For each node the name of the node is considered the key and it's text the "value". So if you want to specify the key for a node simply set its Name property.